# React: Input range slider not propagating last value to its owner in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, reactjs

The following fiddle uses React 0.13 to display 3 input ranges as controlled components. Upon state change, the colored square updates to show the new rgb color. http://jsfiddle.net/faria/yw6q3s9L/

It works as I expect/desire in Firefox, but not in Chrome. Specifically, the colored square component is displaying the penultimate value, whereas the sliders are showing the most recent value.

Is this a React/Chrome bug? or can I fix something in my code?

Code:

```
var ColorDisplay = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        red: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        green: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        blue: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
    },
    _toHex: function(s) {
        var hex = parseInt(s,10).toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    },
    render: function() {
        var rr = this._toHex(this.props.red),
            gg = this._toHex(this.props.green),
            bb = this._toHex(this.props.blue);
        var color = "#" + rr + gg + bb;
        var divStyle = {backgroundColor: color};
        return (
            <div id="display">
                <h3>{color}</h3>
                <div id="color-swatch" style={divStyle}></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var ColorSlider = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        red: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        green: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        blue: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        changeHandler: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            red: this.props.red,
            green: this.props.green,
            blue: this.props.blue
            };
    },
    handleOnChange: function(name, event) {
        var new_state = {};
        new_state[name] = event.target.value;
        this.setState(new_state);
        this.props.changeHandler();
    },
    handleClick: function(name, event) {
        var new_state = {};
        var self = this;
        ['red','green','blue'].forEach(function(name) {
            new_state[name] = React.findDOMNode(self.refs[name]).value;
        });
        this.setState(new_state);
        this.props.changeHandler();
    },
    _getRGB: function() {
        return this.state;
    },
    _toHex: function(s) {
        var hex = parseInt(s,10).toString(16);
        return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
    },
    render: function() {
        var red_style = {color: 'red'};
        var grn_style = {color: 'green'};
        var blue_style = {color: 'blue'};
        var min=0;
        var max=255;
        var step=1;
        var rr = this._toHex(this.state.red),
            gg = this._toHex(this.state.green),
            bb = this._toHex(this.state.blue);
        return (
            <div id="slider">
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="id_red">Red</label>
                    <input
                        name="red"
                        type="range"
                        min={min}
                        max={max}
                        step={step}
                        value={this.state.red}
                        onInput={this.handleOnChange.bind(this, "red")}
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this, "red")}
                        ref="red"
                        id="id_red"
                        />
                    <span style={red_style}>{this.state.red} / {rr}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="id_green">Green</label>
                    <input
                        name="green"
                        type="range"
                        min={min}
                        max={max}
                        step={step}
                        value={this.state.green}
                        onInput={this.handleOnChange.bind(this, "green")}
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this, "green")}
                        ref="green"
                        id="id_green"
                        />
                    <span style={grn_style}>{this.state.green} / {gg}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="id_blue">Blue</label>
                    <input
                        name="blue"
                        type="range"
                        min={min}
                        max={max}
                        step={step}
                        value={this.state.blue}
                        onInput={this.handleOnChange.bind(this, "blue")}
                        onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this, "blue")}
                        ref="blue"
                        id="id_blue"
                        />
                    <span style={blue_style}>{this.state.blue} / {bb}</span>
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Set Color (hack to sync slider with square on Chrome)</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 };
    },
    update: function() {
        var rgb = this.refs.slider._getRGB();
        // the values are now strings!
        this.setState({
            red: rgb.red,
            green: rgb.green,
            blue: rgb.blue
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div id="color-app">
                <ColorDisplay ref="color"
                    red={this.state.red}
                    green={this.state.green}
                    blue={this.state.blue}
                />
                <ColorSlider ref="slider"
                    red={this.state.red}
                    green={this.state.green}
                    blue={this.state.blue}
                    changeHandler={this.update}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
});
React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a race condition in your `handleOnChange` in `ColorSlider`.  You should be calling `this.props.changeHandler()` once the state has been updated not directly after calling `setState`.  This is because `setState` is NOT synchronous.  However the reason why it might work in Firefox correctly is because it's likely a very quick race, and firefox just happens to be coming out on the side that doesn't show an error.

To force it to always work and eliminate the race, use something like this for `handleOnChange` in `ColorSlider`:

```
handleOnChange: function(name, event) {
    var new_state = {};
    new_state[name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(new_state, function() {
        this.props.changeHandler();
    });
}
```

And it'll work just fine.  What this does is make sure that `this.props.changeHandler` only gets called after the state has actually updated and been rendered.  It's for this specific reason that `setState` has an optional callback.

Note that you don't have to bind the callback in `setState` to `this` because React will auto-bind it for you.

**Further edit:**

You also only get this problem occurring at all because you're calling a child components function directly from a parent (bad) and you're reading the data directly from the DOM when you needn't.  Calling a component's method from outside itself is a huge no-no in React.  What you should be doing instead is passing the new colour value up the chain via the onChange callbacks and reacting to it that way in the parent.

EG:

```
handleOnChange: function(name, event) {
  var new_state = {};
  new_state[name] = event.target.value;
  this.setState(new_state, function() {
    this.props.changeHandler(name, this.state[name]);
  })
}
```

Allowing you to set the colour change in the parent `App` component via changing your `update` function to something like:

```
update: function(name, value) {
  var stateChange = {};
  stateChange[name] = value;
  this.setState(stateChange);
}
```

Comment: "setState is NOT synchronous", and "pass the new value up the chain"....that was an important lesson for me, thanks.